# `docker-machine scp` from local directory to machine

Tags: docker, scp, docker-machine

I'm trying to copy over some certificates from my computer to a `docker-machine` provisioned DigitalOcean droplet.

```
docker-machine scp /local/path/to/certs/* machine-name:/etc/secure/
```

This gives me an error `Improper number of arguments`. Given that the usage doc says:

```
Arguments are [machine:][path] [machine:][path]
```

I'm not really sure how to achieve what I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the * wildcard will be replaced by the shell with all the files in `/local/path/to/certs`. So `docker-machine scp` receives more than 2 arguments hence the error.

I guess you should use the -r flag to copy the content of one folder to another folder.